# protobuf - field name with special characters

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to manually model a `.proto` file representing a JSON which has one of the field names with a dot and an @ sign. I'm getting an error that doesn't explicitly say that a dot (.) or `@` is disallowed. The error message received while building the Java proto library, when the field name is `@odata.nextLink` is, `Expected field name.` and when the field name is `odata.nextLink` is, `Missing field number.`

Is there a way to work it around? Jackson has a [`JsonProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html#value()) annotation where could specify the actual field name in the JSON representation, while you could pick up a sane field name in the Java class.

In case you're curious, this is related to [Open Data Protocol](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#entitySet) where their naming conventions are like that.

Comment: It's not clear *exactly* what you're doing with the JSON. Are you manually modelling it, autogenerating a .proto file, or something different? And what language are you parsing this in?

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm manually modelling the .proto and trying to deserialize the JSON to the generated model.

Comment: Okay, so please include that information in the question - along with which language you're using.

Comment: "_an error that doesn't explicitly say_". So, what **does** the error say?

Comment: Please see the latest edit.

Answer (score 3):

There is always a way to work it around :) But i'm not sure if it's worth the effort. First thing to say, PB fields have strict naming conventions, [in proto files](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/style#message-and-field-names) as well as [in Java generated code](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#fields). No hack to get your special characters in. Annotations are not a simple way out either. Java proto code is generated, so you would have to modify the compiler to add the annotations. It's [opensource](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java) so technically doable. Practically... it's up to you :)

As you said that you're *manually modelling* proto files, my recommendation is to make up some kind of naming convention (say, replace `.` -> `_` and `@` -> `_at_`). Then translate Odata names and call getters/setters through Java Reflection.

Comment: yeah, figured it has to be hacky. thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

proto3 has a `json_name` option now that you may be able to use for this.
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json
See the "Notes" section for the `message` proto3 type.